# Slow futures.ProcessPoolExecutor: how to improve?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm trying to understand why the following code is so slow:

```py
import threading
import time
import concurrent.futures
from datetime import datetime


def dump(txt):
    print(f'[{datetime.now()}] ({threading.get_ident():05}) {txt}\n', end='')


def sleep_(_):
    dump('Start')
    time.sleep(0.1)
    dump('Stop')


def main(n=10, processes=10):
    dump('before with')
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(processes) as pool:
        dump('before map')
        tmp = list(pool.map(sleep_, range(n)))
        dump('after map')
    dump('after with')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is the result:

```
[2020-10-17 23:34:12.822813] (07100) before with
[2020-10-17 23:34:12.824808] (07100) before map
[2020-10-17 23:34:21.409045] (14100) Start
[2020-10-17 23:34:21.414031] (15408) Start
[2020-10-17 23:34:21.414031] (20292) Start
[2020-10-17 23:34:21.415029] (18972) Start
[2020-10-17 23:34:21.416026] (13660) Start
[2020-10-17 23:34:21.416026] (10904) Start
[2020-10-17 23:34:21.417023] (18828) Start
[2020-10-17 23:34:21.418021] (18616) Start
[2020-10-17 23:34:21.504788] (01776) Start
[2020-10-17 23:34:21.509775] (14100) Stop
[2020-10-17 23:34:21.509775] (14100) Start
[2020-10-17 23:34:21.514761] (20292) Stop
[2020-10-17 23:34:21.514761] (15408) Stop
[2020-10-17 23:34:21.515760] (18972) Stop
[2020-10-17 23:34:21.516757] (13660) Stop
[2020-10-17 23:34:21.516757] (10904) Stop
[2020-10-17 23:34:21.517754] (18828) Stop
[2020-10-17 23:34:21.518751] (18616) Stop
[2020-10-17 23:34:21.605519] (01776) Stop
[2020-10-17 23:34:21.610506] (14100) Stop
[2020-10-17 23:34:21.611503] (07100) after map
[2020-10-17 23:34:23.281562] (07100) after with
```

What I'm trying to understand here is, is why it takes nearly 9 seconds to start the first process. And why it takes nearly 2 seconds to clear up them?

This is a windows system (under debug).
When I run it normally, it would take +- 0.5s to spin up and to wind down.

Compared to a Debian WSL on the same system: 0.04s to spin up & 0.006s to wind down.

Is this normal behaviour? And/or how to improve on it? And why does this happen?

Thanks!

Comment: On non-Windows, processes are created with "fork" which basically creates a lazy copy (copy on write) of the main process. This is fast while Windows has to create the processes by starting a new interpreter and executing the full Python code (except the guarded main part at the end) to set up the process.

Comment: Could you make this comment into an answer? As your answer was first and provided slightly more (unknown to me) information than James' one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux and other Unix-like operating systems processes are created with `fork` system call which basically creates a lazy copy (copy on write) of the main process. This is a fast operation.

Windows has no `fork` functionality so has to create each worker process by starting a new interpreter and executing the full Python code (except the guarded `if __name__ == '__main__':` part at the end) to set up the process before it can be used. Python calls this "spawn" method in the [multiprocessing docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods).

Since Python 3.8 the spawn method is also the default on MacOS.

Answer (score 0):

Windows does not have the equivalent of the `fork` system call to duplicate a process.  This means that using a multiprocessing pool with 10 workers in Windows will create 10 **new** python processes.

It doesn't take 9 seconds to start the first process, it takes 9 seconds to start all 10 processes in the pool and then fire the target function to the first process.